# Keyboard codes translation

Tags: c#, linux, windows, keyboard, keycode

I'm creating some remote control tool in C# from Windows to Linux which I got working.

The only problem I'm facing is translating the key codes from Windows to Linux. Is there any formula, table or tool to do this conversion?

If it helps, on windows I get the key codes from the KeyUp/KeyDown events and on the linux side i'm using uinput to generate the events.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an elegant solution based on an idea of [Dietrich Epp](https://github.com/depp). The idea is based on using the USB HID codes as an intermediate common point.

I got from [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/hid-input.c) the linux key mappings to HID and from [here](https://github.com/depp/keycode) the windows ones.

And this is the final result:

```
    public static byte[] linux_hid_keyboard = new byte[] 
    {
        255,  255,  255,  255, 30, 48, 46, 32, 18, 33, 34, 35, 23, 36, 37, 38,
        50, 49, 24, 25, 16, 19, 31, 20, 22, 47, 17, 45, 21, 44,  2,  3,
        4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 28,  1, 14, 15, 57, 12, 13, 26,
        27, 43, 43, 39, 40, 41, 51, 52, 53, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64,
        65, 66, 67, 68, 87, 88, 99, 70,119,110,102,104,111,107,109,106,
        105,108,103, 69, 98, 55, 74, 78, 96, 79, 80, 81, 75, 76, 77, 71,
        72, 73, 82, 83, 86,127,116,117,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,
        191,192,193,194,134,138,130,132,128,129,131,137,133,135,136,113,
        115,114,255,255,255,121,255, 89, 93,124, 92, 94, 95,255,255,255,
        122,123, 90, 91, 85,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,111,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,179,180,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,111,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        29, 42, 56,125, 97, 54,100,126,164,166,165,163,161,115,114,113,
        150,158,159,128,136,177,178,176,142,152,173,140,255,255,255,255
    };

    public static byte[] windows_hid_keyboard = new byte[]  
    {
        255,255,255,255, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76,
        77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 49, 50,
        51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 48, 13, 27,  8,  9, 32,189,187,219,
        221,220,255,186,222,192,188,190,191, 20,112,113,114,115,116,117,
        118,119,120,121,122,123, 44,145, 19, 45, 36, 33, 46, 35, 34, 39,
        37, 40, 38,144,111,106,109,107,255, 97, 98, 99,100,101,102,103,
        104,105, 96,110,255,255,255,255,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,
        132,133,134,135,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        17, 16, 18,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,
        255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255
    };

    public static Dictionary<int, int> GetTranslationWindowsToLinux()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> trans = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int buc = 0; buc < 256; buc++)
        {
            int lin = linux_hid_keyboard[buc];
            int win = windows_hid_keyboard[buc];

            if (lin != 255 && win != 255 && !trans.ContainsKey(win))
                trans.Add(win, lin);
        }

        return trans;
    }

    public static Dictionary<int, int> GetTranslationLinuxToWindows()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> trans = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        for (int buc = 0; buc < 256; buc++)
        {
            int lin = linux_hid_keyboard[buc];
            int win = windows_hid_keyboard[buc];

            if (lin != 255 && win != 255 && !trans.ContainsKey(lin))
                trans.Add(lin, win);
        }

        return trans;
    }
```

Hope it helps someone in my same situation.